# How to update a Fragment after an AsyncTask finishes in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There is probably a very simple way to do this that will only require one or two lines of code, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I want to have fragments that initially display a loading gif in the center of the screen, then it will start an AsyncTask which downloads information from my server. After the AsyncTask is complete, I will need to set the content view of the Fragment to a different xml file, then display some of what I got from the server.

I was thinking there should be some type of function like `Fragment.invalidate()` or `Fragment.refresh()` that could help update the Fragment, but I can't seem to find any such function.

Also, if I update the Fragment in a different function outside of the `onCreateView` function, do I need to create variables to hold the `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup` objects that are initially passed to it, or can I access these using function calls? Below is roughly what I want to do...

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading, container, false);

        (new GetDataTask()).execute(1);

        return view;
    }


    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ServerResponse>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        @Override
        protected ServerResponse doInBackground(Integer... args)
        {
            int page_num = args[0];
            return Server.getPosts(page_num);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ServerResponse result)
        {
            /*
                1. Update the content view to R.layout.multi_post_list
                2. Change specific text views and image views (I know how to do this part)
                3. Notify that changes have been made to the Fragment, so it needs redrawn
            */
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** ServerResponse is a class that I created, and Server.getPosts is a static function that returns a ServerResponse. I know that these work in my case. I need help with points 1 and 3 in my `onPostExecute` part of my `GetDataTask` class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **findFragmentByTag**

```
DetailsFragment df = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("details");
    if (df != null) {
        df.setShownIndex(getSelectedIndex());
    } else {
        df = DetailsFragment.newInstance(getSelectedIndex());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, df, "details").commit();
```

Comment: Not sure where this `getSelectedIndex()` is coming from? There is no method like that in Fragment.java

Comment: https://github.com/jayway/FragmentsLab/blob/master/src/com/jayway/lab/fragments/DetailsFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. Use AsyncTaskLoader instead of AsyncTask to prevent reloading your data after a screen rotation.  Or call `setRetainInstance(true)` on the Fragment to prevent the Fragment from being destroyed on rotation. (just be careful to handle detached state)
2. You can get the Activity's root view by calling `getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` and manipulate it however you need to.  You could also just create one layout that has both states and show/hide parts of them has needed.
3. You can get the inflater at any time by calling `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())`